# Read multiple selection from TableView in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: java, javafx-2, selectionmodel

I am trying to get the selection from a TableView in JavaFX 2.0. I have stored 5 Persons (5 rows) in the TableView. The code to get the selection model is:

```
TableView<Person> tableView =
myStage.getTableView();

ObservableList<Person> selection = 
tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

System.out.println(selection.size());
```

Now when I select multiple rows and then execute the method including the above code, the following prints the selection * 2 and sometimes the selection * 3. For example: I select all 5 rows and it prints out a size of 10 and sometimes 15!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug with TableView returning duplicated items for selection made by shift-click.
As a workaround until fix you can try filter duplicated items by:

```
Set<Person> selection = new HashSet<Person>(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly fine! Well, I expected to run into some bugs in JavaFX 2.0 and here we go.